# Colocar uma combobox numa coluna de um datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

Usando o C#, com EntityFramework e codefirst, tenho as seguintes classes na minha camada de models:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}

    public class Endereco
    {
        public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Rua { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cidade { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxaDeEntrega { get; set; }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public virtual  Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }

    public class Telefone
    {
        public int TelefoneId { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public int ClienteID { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
```

Na minha camada de Forms, eu tenho um form com um datagridview com as colunas de nome do cliente, email, data de cadastro e uma combobox com as listas de telefones de cada um. Essas configurações estão montadas da seguinte forma:

```
private void FormClientes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Não exibe os ícones de Maximixação e minimização do form dentro de uma MDI Parent
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            dataGridViewClientes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridViewClientes.RowHeadersVisible = false;//Omite a primeira coluna

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colNome = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colNome.HeaderText = "NOME";
            colNome.DataPropertyName = "Nome";
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add(colNome);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colEmail = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colEmail.HeaderText = "EMAIL";
            colEmail.DataPropertyName = "Email";
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add(colEmail);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colDataCadastro = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colDataCadastro.HeaderText = "DATA CADASTRO";
            colDataCadastro.DataPropertyName = "DataCadastro";
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add(colDataCadastro);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colTelefones = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            colTelefones.HeaderText = "TELEFONES";
            colTelefones.DataPropertyName = "Numero";
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add(colTelefones);

            FillDataGrid();
        }

        private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            foreach (var c in _clienteApp.GetAll())
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

                foreach (var t in c.Telefones)
                {
                    cbc.Items.Add(t.Numero);
                }

                dataGridViewClientes.Rows.Add(c.Nome, c.Email, c.DataCadastro, cbc);
            }
        }
```

Na função `FillDataGrid()`  eu pego os dados do BD e populo as colunas. O problema está quando eu vou adicionar a combobox de telefones ao final da linha. O programa compila mas ao carregar o form a combo não é montada e eu tenho a seguinte exception:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu retirar o `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` as linhas são montadas mas a combobox fica sem os telefones. Também já tentei montar uma `Combobox` e adicionar ela ao final da linha `dataGridViewClientes.Rows.Add(c.Nome, c.Email, c.DataCadastro, ... );` mas não obtive sucesso. Onde estou errando ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segui algumas dicas de um colega do Stackoverflow em inglês @JohnG e consegui fazer o que eu queria. [How to put a combobox on datagridview programmatically iterating a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986058/how-to-put-a-combobox-on-datagridview-programmatically-iterating-a-collection). Abaixo segue o código que fiz:

```
private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            ConfiguraPaginacao();

            dgvClientes.Rows.Clear();
            dgvClientes.Columns.Clear();

            var colNome = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colNome.HeaderText = "NOME";
            colNome.DataPropertyName = "Nome";
            colNome.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

            var colEmail = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colEmail.HeaderText = "EMAIL";
            colEmail.DataPropertyName = "Email";
            colEmail.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

            var colDataCadastro = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colDataCadastro.HeaderText = "DATA CADASTRO";
            colDataCadastro.DataPropertyName = "DataCadastro";
            colDataCadastro.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

            var colTelefones = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            colTelefones.HeaderText = "TELEFONES";
            colTelefones.DataPropertyName = "Numero";
            colTelefones.Name = "Telefones";
            colTelefones.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

            dgvClientes.Columns.Add(colNome);
            dgvClientes.Columns.Add(colEmail);
            dgvClientes.Columns.Add(colDataCadastro);
            dgvClientes.Columns.Add(colTelefones);

            foreach (var c in _clienteApp.GetAllToPagination(paginaAtual, itensPorPagina).ToList())
            {
                int index = dgvClientes.Rows.Add(c.Nome, c.Email, c.DataCadastro);

                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvClientes.Rows[index].Cells["Telefones"];
                cb.DataSource = c.Telefones.ToList();
                cb.ValueMember = "Numero";
                cb.DisplayMember = "Numero";

                //Exibe o primeiro número de telefone na combobox
                if (c.Telefones.Count > 0)
                    cb.Value = c.Telefones.First().Numero.ToString();
            }

            dgvClientes.Sort(dgvClientes.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        }
```

Depois estudando melhor, notei que o `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` já é adicionado automaticamente ao final da linha como se fosse já um `Combobox`. O que precisa ser feito depois é preencher a lista que o `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` tem. Eu adiciono os campos texto na linha `int index = dgvClientes.Rows.Add(c.Nome, c.Email, c.DataCadastro);` menos a lista do combobox. Em `index`, eu pego qual linha estou. Em seguida eu pego o `combobox` dessa linha: `DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvClientes.Rows[index].Cells["Telefones"];` e preencho já com os objetos da lista.

```
cb.DataSource = c.Telefones.ToList();
                cb.ValueMember = "Numero";
                cb.DisplayMember = "Numero";
```

Outra dica legal é que para manter selecionado o primeiro item da `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` , eu só tenho a propriedade value.

```
//Exibe o primeiro número de telefone na combobox
if (c.Telefones.Count > 0){
   cb.Value = c.Telefones.First().Numero.ToString();
}
```